# Read static XML file on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a static XML file in my App Engine app that uploads just fine and I am trying to read it for some rules based execution logic, but the below error is thrown at me:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission /war/WEB-INF/StaticContent.xml read)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:393)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:553)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:166)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:130)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:96)
```

I tried placing the file both directly in the war and in the `war/WEB-INF` directories, the problem persists. The on the server attempts to read the file is as simple as this:

```
final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/war/WEB-INF/StaticContent.xml");
```

According to this article, I am doing everything correctly:
http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/java.html#readfile

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

Use getResourceAsStream instead of directly opening a FileInputStream.

The location you specify in FileInputStream is taken as an absolute location which is why you are getting hte access denied exception.

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
InputStream is = context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/StaticContent.xml");
```

Comment: I used .getRealPath instead of .getResourceAsStream and it is working fine.

Comment: how to access it when in endpoint class, so the context is not accessible?

Comment: The ServletContext is accessible in endpoint methods. You can just add the ServletContext as a parameter, and the framework will inject it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reading from `war/WEB-INF/StaticContent.xml` instead of `/war/WEB-INF/StaticContent.xml`? It may be that the latter is interpreted as an absolute path, when in fact you don't know what the absolute path is and thus want a relative path.

Comment: That throws another error, the problem seemed to be the path, look at this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/google-appengine-java&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&parenturl=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fappengine%2Fforum%2Fjava-forum.html%3Fplace%3Dforum%2Fgoogle-appengine-java#!searchin/google-appengine-java/read$20static$20file/google-appengine-java/ltgp3DuTx7M/h8GCC9yMD4AJ

Answer (score 0):

If your file is stored in war Directory then you can access that without specifying project name in filepath:

project-
      war-
         sample.json

then access file with path as- FileReader fr=new FileReader("war/sample.json");

:)

Answer (score -1):

I found that the following worked for me:

```
InputStream feedStream = new FileInputStream("WEB-INF/" + fileName);
```

Comment: It's causing: AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/WEB-INF/emails/activation_template" "read")